# Flexdashboard with Shiny - Widget Font Style

Tags: shiny, flexdashboard

Hi I am building a dashboard using Flexdashboard and including shiny features. I included a sidebar with Date Range, I am trying to change the Font_Style to show it bold. I tried the following but its not working, any ideas:

```
br()
tags$style("label {font-style: bold;}")
dateRangeInput("dates", label = h6("DATE RANGE"))
hr()
```

[Widget Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzo0H.png)

Comment: try `tags$style(".input-group-addon {font-weight: bold;}")`. Note that the class is `input-group-addon` and use `font-weight: bold` instead,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `tags$style(".input-group-addon {font-weight: bold;}")`. Note that the class is `input-group-addon` and use `font-weight: bold` instead,..

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(".input-group-addon {font-weight: bold;}"),
  dateRangeInput(inputId = "a", label = "", start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date())
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: My first Stack Overflow question... Checked :)